# Making a list of all classnames in the Python inheritance tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

My end goal is to try an alternative way to make type equality tests at runtime by checking an ancestor list of all the classnames. This does require that I own all the classes I want to typecheck this way and that's ok. The way I'm calling `super` here isn't quite right, but maybe there's a better way to create this list.

This would allow me to replace my existing
`isinstance(x, Child)` checks with `Child.__name__ in x.typetags()`

```
class HasTypeTags():
    @classmethod
    def typetags(cls):
        try:
            return cls._typetags
        except:
            cls._typetags = [cls.__name__]
            for base in cls.__bases__:
                cls._typetags.append(base.__name__)
            try:
                cls._typetags += super(cls, cls).typetags()
            except:
                pass
                
            return cls._typetags

class Root(HasTypeTags, object):
    pass

class Child(Root):
    pass

class GrandChild(Child):
    pass


grandchild = GrandChild()
print(grandchild.typetags())
# should output something like ['GrandChild', 'Child', 'Root', 'HasTypeTags', 'object']
# but actually prints ['GrandChild', 'Child', 'GrandChild', 'Child']
```

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate by another post that does not answer this question at all.

Comment: Please read the answers to the linked question. Either the `__mro__` attribute or the `mro` method of a class object would suffice.

Comment: `Root in type(grandchild).mro()` does provide the check I'm looking for.